# What is the significance of $\mathscr F$ being algebra in defining measure?

Tags: measure-theory

I know that if $S$ is a non-empty set and $\mathscr F$ is an algebra on $S$ then a function $\mu$ on $\mathscr F$ is called measure if

(i) $\mu(A)\in [0, \infty]$ for all $A \in\mathscr F$,

(ii) $\mu(\emptyset) = 0$,

(iii) $\mu\left(\displaystyle\bigcup_{n=1}^\infty A_n \right) = \displaystyle\sum_{n=1}^\infty \mu(A_n)$, where $\{A_n\}$ is a disjoint collection of members of $\mathscr F$, with $\left(\displaystyle\bigcup_{n=1}^\infty A_n \right) \in\mathscr F$.

My question is what is the significance of $\mathscr F$ being algebra? Can we take it to be semi-algebra?

(PS - I don't know how to make use of mathematical symbols here, please edit the question accordingly)

Comment: You may learn mathjax to write math symbols from here https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference very easily.

Comment: I edited as you have written, but you are missing a fact, the assumption that $\bigcup_{n=1}^\infty A_n\in\mathscr F$, whenever $\{A_n\}$ is a collection of pairwise disjoint sets from the **algebra** $\mathscr F$.

Comment: Thank you for the edit. Oh sorry, I missed the fact. will edit. Thanks.

Comment: No, $\mathcal{F}$ must be a $\sigma$-*algebra* in order to define a measure. A function $\mu$ satisfying the OP's criteria (along with the additional criterion mentioned by @0-thUser) defines a *premeasure*.

Comment: @Mark thank you for your comment. But what is OP's criteria. I haven't heard the term before.

Comment: @Mathematic_ally OP stands for "original poster" (or something like that), so that's you. By "OP's criteria," I mean your points (i) to (iii).

Comment: @Mark okay, thanks.Yeah, this is my question, what is the reason that we cannot take $\mathscr F$ to be algebra or semi-algebra. Like what is the significance of taking it to be sigma algebra here?

Comment: @Mathematic_ally I think it's just a question of motivation. That is, measures are defined on $\sigma$-algebras because we *want* the countable additivity, so we need an algebra that is closed not just under finite unions but under countably infinite unions, i.e. we need a $\sigma$-algebra. You can define some concept similar to measures on algebras, but I presume it would be less useful/interesting.

Comment: @Mark Thank you. I got the required direction.

Answer (score 1):

Usually, one uses "measure" to talk about a measure over a $\sigma$-algebra. However, some people use only algebras, others are happy with semi-rings. And some people are happy calling "measure" what many would call an *outer measure*.

**Why do people like semi-rings?**

You look at $1 \times 1$ squares and you think: this has the area of a $1 \times 1$ square. Then, you look at rectangles and think... well I think I know the area of this $a \times b$ rectangle. It should be $ab$. Congratulations, you have defined area for a semi-ring or a semi-algebra, if you allow for infinite rectangles.

Semi-rings arise naturally, in my opinion, because of the rectangles (or cillinders).

**Why do people like algebras?**

Then, you realize that you can easily measure the area of finite unions of disjoint rectangles. Now, you have defined area for a ring... or an algebra, if you allow infinite rectangles.

People like algebras, in my opinion, because the definition is simpler. And since extending a $\sigma$-additive function over a semi-algebra to the generated algebra is very simple, some people tend (in my opinion) to favoring "algebras".

**Why do people like $\sigma$-algebras?**

Wouldn't it be nice if you could tell the area of a circle? Or, maybe, the area "below the graph" of a function...

But a cirlce is not in the algebra generated by the rectangles. You probably want to take limits of sets. You can approximate a circle using squares. Using this approximations in a consistent way, you can now measure the area of circles. The circle is in the $\sigma$-algebra.

At the end, what you really want (in my opinion), is a measure over a $\sigma$-algebra. There is a theorem (Carathéodory extension theorem) that states that you can always extend a "measure" defined over xxx to a "full measure" over the $\sigma$=algebra generated by xxx.

So, the questions sums up to whether you prefer to extend it form a semi-algebra xxx or from an algebra xxx.

Comment: Can you please elaborate the consequence you are driving from the answer you provided.